# Assign array value into new variable inside the loop changed the original array value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I am using wordpress and fetching some records from the Mysql.
I have three type of account access "Type1", "Type2" and "Both". I want to change the "Both" type of array item into 2 array with Type1 and Type2.

Here is my response from Mysql.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 583
            [username] => test1@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 1
            [user_pass] => oN3WIffffffMW
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test1@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type1
            [customer_school_id] => 5455
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1534
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => hh534446gr
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 1
            [email] => test1@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 55555
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => GA
            [postal] => 444
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 4466dgg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 584
            [username] => test2@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 2
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test2@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type2
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test2@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 4433rrfty66
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 585
            [username] => test3@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 3
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Both
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 44dd3rrfty66
        )

)
```

Here is my code:-
$all_records contains above array value.

```
$all_records1 = array();
if (!empty($all_records) && count($all_records) > 0) {

    foreach($all_records as $key => $allitems ) {

        if($allitems->account_access == 'Both') {
             $newItem = $allitems;
             $allitems->account_access ='Type1';
             $newItem->account_access ='Type2';
              array_push($all_records1,$allitems);
             array_push($all_records1,$newItem);
        } else {
              array_push($all_records1,$allitems);
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_records1);   echo "</pre>";  die;
}
```

Its gives me following result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 583
            [username] => test1@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 1
            [user_pass] => oN3WIffffffMW
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test1@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type1
            [customer_school_id] => 5455
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1534
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => hh534446gr
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 1
            [email] => test1@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 55555
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => GA
            [postal] => 444
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 4466dgg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 584
            [username] => test2@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 2
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test2@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type2
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test2@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 4433rrfty66
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 585
            [username] => test3@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 3
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type2
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 44dd3rrfty66
        ) 

        [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 585
            [username] => test3@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 3
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type2
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 44dd3rrfty66
        )

)
```

But It should give the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 583
            [username] => test1@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 1
            [user_pass] => oN3WIffffffMW
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test1@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type1
            [customer_school_id] => 5455
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1534
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => hh534446gr
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 1
            [email] => test1@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 55555
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => GA
            [postal] => 444
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 4466dgg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 584
            [username] => test2@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 2
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test2@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type2
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test2@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 4433rrfty66
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 585
            [username] => test3@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 3
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type1
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 44dd3rrfty66
        ) 

        [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 585
            [username] => test3@yopmail.com
            [name] => Test 3
            [user_pass] => QJWBsKfgggggszSk
            [school_name] => Test SCHOOL
            [customer_email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [trial_account] => 
            [expiry_date] => 2021-05-16
            [old_expiry_date] => 
            [created_date] => 2020-05-13 05:15:24
            [status] => 1
            [email_status] => 0
            [account_access] => Type2
            [customer_school_id] => 3333
            [is_parent] => 0
            [parent_id] => 1532
            [logged_count] => 0
            [library_count] => 0
            [starting_ip_address] => 
            [ending_ip_address] => 
            [district_id] => 
            [company] => test
            [37_days_flag] => 0
            [stop_email] => 0
            [monthly_emails] => 0
            [sent_monthly_email] => 
            [pwd_for_mail] => QJWBggg335KzSk
            [welcome_email] => 0
            [send_bcc] => 0
            [is_from_bulk] => 1
            [customer_name] => Test 2
            [email] => test3@yopmail.com
            [id_code] => 566666
            [customer_school] => Test SCHOOL
            [address] => Test
            [city] => Test
            [state] => NC
            [postal] => 455555
            [country] => US
            [telephone] => 555555
            [library_login_url] => 44dd3rrfty66
        )

)
```

Any idea what i am missing in this code?

Comment: Make your mind up! What code are you really using?

Comment: Does that new code produce the same problem?

Comment: I think you would need `print_r($all_records1, true);` in that situation

Comment: @RiggsFolly , Sorry i was  put the wrong code before, Now its correct code

Comment: thx Arun for sharing this great example of an array with us. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was an array of array your code would work, however because its an array of object when you copy the array it does not clone the object inside the array occurance it keeps a reference. So when you amend the `account_access` property it is in fact a reference so a change is applied to the original. The effect of that is your second change to `account_access` also changes the first as well.

So you need to clone the object inside the array to make sure you are getting a unique copy of that object

```
$all_records1 = array();
if (!empty($all_records) && count($all_records) > 0) {

    foreach($all_records as $key => $item ) {

        if($item->account_access == 'Both') {   
            $copy = clone $item;
            $copy->account_access = 'Type1';
            $all_records1[] = $copy;

            $copy = clone $item;
            $copy->account_access = 'Type2';
            $all_records1[] = $copy;
        } else {
            $all_records1[] = $item;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_records1);   echo "</pre>";  die;
}
```

I also changed `array_push()` as you are only pushing one item onto the new array it is quicker to do a simple `$arr[]=$var` as then you dont call a function therefore you dont have that overhead, its tiny, but to be honest I prefer that construct over `array_push()`